# Openstreetmap add css class to marker

Tags: jquery, css, openlayers-3

I'm using OpenLayers and I want to add a specific CSS class to highlight a marker. The marker is a .png image, and I can't find the propper way to add the css class to modify its style

Here is an example of the same image with and without style. I want to add in the map the stylished marker

http://jsfiddle.net/Ljq79s85/

```
var myStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
       src: 'push_pin.png'
    })
});
```

Comment: `element.classList.add("classname")` ?

Comment: And what is 'element' in this particular case?

Comment: any HTMLElement (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)